# Is it okay to ask the following question what statistical models can be used in X?

Tags: discussion

Is it okay to ask what statistical and machine learning models can be used in SEM optimization or product design, for example?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO that sounds on-topic for Data Science, yes. A combination of statistics and its application sounds quite relevant as a topic.

Comment: I think it it is relevant as a topic, but it is open-ended as well. So that's why I am not sure if that would be acceptable. But I also think open-ended questions may be more acceptable in the DS board vs. stack overflow, because this is a somewhat novel area of interest. A lot of people will come to the DS board with questions on how to start studying the field, what tools are available and similar questions.

Comment: Answers like "use this one" is of course not acceptable. If you are member of the Software Recommendation SE site, you will see that those answers are really detailed and you need to describe exactly the reason why you should choose those tools or models. I believe those, detailed answers should be on-topic.